# Find all $z$ such that $e^{2\pi i z}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to find all $z$ such that $e^{2\pi i z}=1$. I know that if I take $z$ to be an integer, this will be true by periodicity. However, how can I be sure that these are all the solutions? What if there were some other solution that was not an integer?

Comment: Hint: if $z=a+ib$, $e^{2\pi i z}=e^{-2\pi b}e^{2\pi i a}$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I'm not sure I see what to do from here. Maybe something about the term on the right would go away in the modulus? leaving us with $e^{-2\pi b}$? Could I have another hint?

Comment: Further hint: $1=|1|=|e^{-2\pi b}e^{2\pi i a}|=e^{-2\pi b}$. Are you familiar with the graph of $b \mapsto e^{-2\pi b}$?

Comment: @Gary What about $1=|1|=|e^{2\pi i z}||e^{-2\pi b}e^{2\pi i a}|=e^{-2\pi b}$ so it must be $b=0$ which means that only the real part is considered? But what about ruling out every real but non integer solution?

Comment: How about $2\pi k =\arg (1)=\arg (e^{2\pi ia})=2\pi a$? ($k\in \mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: @Gary  Is this saying that the set of arguments is the same? I am sorry for such basic quesitons I am really trying to understand this deeply I think I was pushed into residue calculus before mastering the basics this semester.

Comment: It says that $a$ must be an integer. Alterntively, $1+0\cdot i=1=e^{2\pi ia}=\cos(2\pi a)+i\sin(2\pi a)$. Can you finish?

Comment: @Gary Well I could map this back to what I know about sin and cos where sin is 0 only on 2pi*integer and cos is 1 only on the 2pi *integer. That makes sense thank you! for the argument version, is this saying that two complex numbers are equal iff their raidus and arguments are the same? So we know the argument of 1 is the set of all integers multiples of 2pi so this must equal the argument of $e^{2\pi i a}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for $z=x+iy$

$$1=|1|=|e^{2\pi i(x+iy)}|=|e^{2\pi i x}e^{-2\pi y}|=e^{-2\pi y}$$

Since $-2\pi y$ is a real number, we can take logarithms to get

$$0=\ln(1)=\ln(e^{-2\pi y})=-2\pi y$$

$$\Rightarrow 0=y$$

Alright, so we know $z=x$ for some real $x$. But then

$$1=e^{2\pi i x}=\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)$$

Since $1$ is purely real, this implies

$$0=\sin(2\pi x)$$

$$\Rightarrow 2\pi x=\pi k\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{k}{2}\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

If we use this information with the real part of the expression above, we get

$$1=\cos(2\pi x)=\cos(\pi k)\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\Rightarrow \pi k=2\pi m\text{ for some }m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\Rightarrow k=2 m\text{ for some }m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{k}{2}=\frac{2m}{2}=m\text{ for some }m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

We conclude $x$ must necessarily be an integer. Since it is easy to check that any integer is indeed a solution, we conclude the solution set is the integers.